# Structure of controllers, sub-controllers and views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, viewcontroller

I'm trying to structure my iPhone app and was wondering if I'm on the right track. I'm not using any Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller:

- I start with the AppDelegate and put a rootViewController in it
- This rootViewController inits two other viewControllers and is responsible for swapping between them
- Each of these two viewControllers adds additional viewControllers and is responsible for swapping between them

> ```
>    ROOT
>
>      |
>
> VC1------VC2
>
>           |
>
>      VC2.1---VC2.2----VC2.3 etc.
> ```

I was wondering if this is setup is OK or totally flawed. Should I rather use views instead of viewControllers? In same instances, there is quite a huge hierarchy of viewControllers and I guess this isn't very good practice. E.g. in the example above VC2.3 is called by VC2 which is called by the ROOT viewController.

Comment: If you use navigation controller it would be simple and easy to use for you.

Comment: @iOS Developer But I need to the UI to be 100% customised; with navigation controller I have all these controllers at the top of the screen or all the buttons at the bottom (uitabbar), not?

Comment: You can hide the viewController.navigationItem (proxy object) and have your own UIButtons or whatever custom interface you want to push/pop view controllers from the viewController.navigationController (also a proxy object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above you don't have to have a visible navigation bar in order to use the functionality of the navigation controller. I strongly reccommend you use a navigation controller.